# How did Martha Jones know he had two hearts?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who, season three episode one, the episode titled "Smith and Jones", the doctor lets the plasmavore suck out his blood in order for it to be captured, and passes out from the blood loss.  Martha comes to his rescue and performs cpr, but in the middle of it she somehow realized that he had two hears, and starts pumping his chest in two locations.

I was confused as to how she knew he had two hearts.  How did she know?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the beginning of the episode when The Doctor was "admitted" in the hospital and Martha's class group was making their rounds, Martha volunteered to do the assessment.

Martha came under ridicule because when she went to listen for a heartbeat, she discovered one on both sides of The Doctor's chest.

During this final scene, Martha remembers this and performs CPR properly on the Time Lord.

Comment: oh yeah, completely forgot about that scene!